# Selecting slicer value gives Error if the value is not found in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting Error while selecting Slicer value in a Pivot Tableusing VBA, As if value is not available in the Sets Column,

I need to check if Value is available then only it should Check in the slicer, Else not.

For Eg: If Set3 value is available in the Slicer then only it should check for FALSE or Not.

```
 With Activesheet.pivottable("Sales").PivotFields("Sets")
             .PivotItems("Set1").Visible = False
             .PivotItems("Set2").Visible = False
             .PivotItems("Set3").Visible = False
```

Any Suggestion on it ?

Comment: Loop over the `PivotItems` collection and check the name of each item using something like `Select Case`.  Alternatively wrap those 3 lines in `On Error Resume Next...On Error Goto 0` and you can ignore errors due to missing items.

Comment: @TimWilliams  - Thanks For the Suggestion, Can you please Suggest the Correct Syntax to be used in it , As i am not able to get it

Comment: `pivottable` should be `PivotTables` with s.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```vb
Dim pi As PivotItem
For Each pi In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Sales").PivotFields("Sets").PivotItems
    Select Case pi.Name
         Case "Set1", "Set2", "Set3": pi.Visible = False
    End Select
Next pi
```

Note: you can't hide all of the pivot items, so if all of the other items are also hidden you'll get an error when you try to hide the last one.